# Can't jump to file position in explorer for node_modules file

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I open a file in my normal project source, I can press Ctrl+Shift+E from the editor so that the file is focused within the "explorer" section . This does not work for `node_modules`. I have not added node_modules to `files.exclude`, so the folder shows up in the explorer, but the above behaviour is not observed. Is there a way to jump to a file within node_modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> doesn't reveal the file, it only focuses the Explorer view which has the opened file active by default. So that won't work for files not currently visible in Explorer.

You need the `Reveal in Explorer View` command. It has no keybinding by default. You may find in in tab context menu or in command pallete

[image]

---

edit: it's `search.exclude` option that controls this

> Configure glob patterns for excluding files and folders in fulltext searches and quick open. Inherits all glob patterns from the #files.exclude# setting.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. 



"So that won't work for files not currently visible in Explorer" - but the file _is_ visible in Explorer...

Comment: Lemme make that more exact then

Comment: Hmm, now I'm more confused because I just added `node_modules` to be included in search but still it doesn't make the opened file active.

Comment: Is it still grey in Explorer? There's namy settings that may force it to be ignored

Comment: Yes, grey because it's gitignored, but I have `search.useIgnoreFiles` set to `false`

Answer (score 8):

[Right click the tab -> Reveal in Explore View](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75908098/61624) works if you don't mind following those steps every time, but if you want this to happen automatically, [there is a setting for this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168408#issuecomment-1342513210):

[image]

1. Open Visual Studio Code settings
2. Type `explorer.autoRevealExclude` into the search bar
3. Remove the row that says `**/node_modules`

Now any time you open a file in your node_modules directory, the Explorer View will automatically reveal that file.

Comment: This should be the valid answer, the other one is misleading.. maybe it worked in the past, I don't know. But this one works right now, thank you! I felt annoyed and slowed down by this VSCode behaviour for a long time.

Comment: Dont know why I didnt look this up 5 years back, would have saved me hours of time by now, thanks

Comment: @Alex I don't know if this will make you feel any better, but I wasted hours of time before I decided to look it up too.